# How can I set a date to NULL in Yii?

Tags: php, mysql, validation, datetime, yii

I have a date column that usually takes values as `dd.MM.yyyy`. Its validation rule in the model's `rules()` is this:

```
array('start, end', 'date', 'format' => 'dd.MM.yyyy'),
```

I'm populating the database from a CSV file, and I'd like to be able to set the date to `NULL` (i.e. nothing) if the CSV record is empty. So, I'm doing:

```
if (empty($csv_data)) {
  $user->start = new CDbExpression('NULL');
} else {
  $user->start = $csv_data;
}
```

But I get an error that the date format is invalid. Why is that?

The [`CDateValidator` documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDateValidator) says that the `allowEmpty` property is true by default, so it should be able to set this to `NULL`, right? Note that if I just assing the `""` string to the date, it'll convert it to a `0000-00-00 00:00:00` timestamp, which is not `NULL`.

Comment: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/issues/2056

Comment: I'm not an expert on Yii but looking at the docs you could maybe work around it using this method to check if the value isnull()? http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CValidator#except-detail

Comment: @dInGd0nG Interesting, that explains the failure, thanks.

Comment: @Jason Thank you, but as far as I can see this only works in conjunction with so-called scenarios, i.e. you can't check the actual values being passed, you can only say: Don't apply this rule when a new user is created, or when a user is updated, et cetera.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

in model `rules()`:

```
array('start, end', 'date', 'format' => 'dd.MM.yyyy'),
array('start, end', 'default', 'setOnEmpty' => true, 'value' => null),
```

also,

```
if (empty($csv_data)) {
  $user->start = null;
} ...
```

should do the trick too.

Comment: That rule is exactly what I'm after, since it also works when the date is manually removed from the frontend.

Answer (score 3):

The trivial fix for this is not to set the value *at all* during creation:

```
if (!empty($csv_data)) {
  $user->start = $csv_data;
}
```

This way, the date will not be set and thus appear as empty, which also passes validation.

Answer (score 2):

Assigning a `CDbExpression` to the field will (and should) never pass validation; the validator allows `null` but it definitely cannot allow an arbitrary `CDbExpression` as the value of the field; this should not be surprising.

If you wanted to write `null` to the database then do it simply with `$user->start = null` -- there is no reason to involve `CDbExpression` at all here.

Another approach you could use in case you *did* need to use `CDbExpression` would be to tell [`save`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#save-detail) not to validate the record and do it manually, as in:

```
$attributes = $user->attributeNames();
if (empty($csv_data)) {
    $user->start = new CDbExpression('NULL');
    $attributes = array_diff($attributes, array('start')); // don't validate this
} else {
    $user->start = $csv_data;
}

if ($user->validate($attributes)) { // validate only attributes we want here
    $user->save(false); // no validation at all here
}
```