# Yii framework Invalid datetime format on create

Tags: php, mysql, database, yii

I have such `projects` table structure

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `projects` (
  `project_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `url` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `create_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `create_user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `update_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `update_user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`project_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

when I try to create new record with next form

[image]

Rules in model:

```
public function rules()
    {
        // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
        // will receive user inputs.
        return array(
            array('title, description, url', 'required'),
            array('create_user_id, update_user_id', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
            array('title, url', 'length', 'max'=>255),
            array('create_time, update_time', 'safe'),
            // The following rule is used by search().
            // Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
            array('project_id, title, description, url, create_time, create_user_id, update_time, update_user_id', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
        );
    }
```

I have received error

> CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[22007]:
>   Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '' for column
>   'create_time' at row 1. The SQL statement executed was: INSERT INTO
>   `projects` (`title`, `description`, `url`, `create_time`,
>   `create_user_id`, `update_time`, `update_user_id`) VALUES (:yp0, :yp1,
>   :yp2, :yp3, :yp4, :yp5, :yp6)

Why? How can I tell Yii that datetime fields are not required and can contain default value if not entered.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I set a date to NULL in Yii?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14850081/how-can-i-set-a-date-to-null-in-yii)

Comment: Solution from that article produce error `Project has an invalid validation rule. The rule must specify attributes to be validated and the validator name.`

Comment: The error is meaningless without knowing exactly what the model's attributes and rules are. But we 're talking about simply attaching a validation rule here, this is basic stuff.

Comment: Model is simply generated with standard way from this MySQL table.

Comment: Try manually using $model->create_time=null;
Else try $model->create_time=new CDbExpression('NOW()');

Comment: Where I must to add this? I am new in Yii and BTW this example from book "Web Application Development with Yii and PHP (Second Edition)" and it doesn't work.

Comment: Provide the controller method which renders this view
and the view source ill try to suggest u the solution

Comment: I have updated my previous answer hope this may help u

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this, and as this is self contained behavior inside Yii itself, it should work :

In the Rules model add this :

```
public function behaviors(){
        return array('CTimestampBehavior'=>array(
        'class' => 'zii.behaviors.CTimestampBehavior',
        'createAttribute' => 'create_time',
        'updateAttribute' => 'update_time',
        'setUpdateOnCreate' => true,  
        ));
    }
```

Comment: Yep, CTimestampBehevior is very handy and saves code. I recommend this policy.

Answer (score 1):

U may try something like this after u click on the button Create it gets to some action 
Take it for example actionCreate()
In actionCreate u do like as shown

```
public function actionCreate()
{
$model=new Project;
if(isset($_POST['Project']))
{
$model->attributes=$_POST['Project'];
$model->create_time=new CDbExpression('NOW()');
$model->save(false);
$this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
}
$this->render('create',array(
'model'=>$model,
));
}
```

Comment: I have added rules fragment from my model to this question body, the same situation with this.

Comment: Sorry for that i didn't notice it

Answer (score 0):

doesn't this work?

```
public function beforeSave()
{
    if($this->isNewRecord)
    {
        $this->create_time=null;
        $this->update_time=null;
    }
    return parent::beforeSave();
}
```